# Why does my conditional statement selectively drop the first character in the output string?

Tags: ruby

I have a function that intends to take an integer and return a string by inserting a "-" before or after any odd integer, with the exception of no "-" at the start or end of the output string.

Here's my function (sorry, it's not idiomatic ruby!):

```
def dash_odds(num)
   arr = num.to_s.split("").map {|digit| digit.to_i}
   string = ""
   i = 0
   while i < arr.length
      if arr[i] % 2 == 0
         string = string + arr[i].to_s
      elsif arr[i].to_s % 2 != 0
         new = "-" << arr[i].to_s unless i == 0
         string = string + new.to_s
      else arr[i].to_s % 2 != 0
         new = arr[i].to_s << "-" unless i == -1
         string = string + new.to_s
      end
    i += 1
    end
    return string
end
```

For instance, dash_odds(5227) should correctly yield "5-22-7" but instead returns "22-7".

However, this isn't a problem for integers starting with an even number (i.e. input 2222 or 227 yields, "2222" and "22-7", respectively, as expected).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heh, this feels a bit silly, but it works

```
s.scan(/[13579]|[24680]+/).join('-')
```

**Explanation**

What this does is split the string into an array of strings of either a single odd digit (`[13579]`), or a group of even digits (`[24680]+`). The `+` matches one or more digits, and so allows even digits to group together, while odd digits remain separate.

```
"5227".scan(/[13579]|[24680]+/)
=> ["5", "22", "7"]
"632273170088".scan(/[13579]|[24680]+/)
=> ["6", "3", "22", "7", "3", "1", "7", "0088"]
```

Follow that with a `join` to rebuild the string with dashes between each group.

```
["5", "22", "7"].join('-')
=> "5-22-7"
```

This code assumes string input. If you have numeric input, you must call `to_s` first.

---

**OP's code**

I thought I'd also comment about a couple of things that went wrong in the originally posted code.

First, the `else` does not take a conditional expression. I was at first surprised it didn't produce an error, until I realized it was being interpreted as

```
  else
     arr[i].to_s % 2 != 0  # **Boolean expression with no side effect**
     new = arr[i].to_s << "-" unless i == -1
     string = string + new.to_s
```

It has already entered the else block before it sees the expression. The expression is then treated like any other statement, and it evaluates the expression and then discards the result. (Unless it's the only expression in the block, in which case the result is returned as the value of the block).

Even if the `else` was changed to an `elsif`, it still wouldn't work since the condition is the same as the previous `elsif` and so the last block would never execute since the earlier block would always catch that condition.

```
if exp1
  puts 'exp1 true'
elsif exp2
  puts 'exp2 true'
elsif exp2  # Duplicate expression
  puts 'exp2 true (2)' # Never executed, case already caught above
end
```

Another problem is the conditional expression `arr[i].to_s % 2 != 0` uses `to_s` right before `%`. This means modular arithmetic for integers, but string interpolation for strings. This is like calling `sprintf(string, args)`.

```
5 % 2
=> 1
'A number: %d' % 2
=> "A number: 2"
```

Of course the expression is to test for even or odd, so a simple `else` would work.

Within the else, you could use a nested conditional to test against the position (beginning or end), but then you're in the realm of duplicate dashes in the case where you have consecutive odd numbers. I problem I was avoiding trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks Daniel!  Can you please show / explain how this works so I can accept you answer. :)  I am trying to run in it in the above function basically replacing the while loop with it but running into some errors.

Comment: @Codestudio: Replace your whole method body with that line, and change the `s` to match your parameter name `num`. I'll add more explanation in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try replace your while loop with something like this...

```
ends_in_dash = false
while i < arr.length
   if arr[i] % 2 == 1 && i > 0 && !ends_in_dash
     string += "-"
   end

   string = string + arr[i].to_s
   ends_in_dash = false

   if arr[i] % 2 == 1 && i < arr.length - 1
     string += "-"
     ends_in_dash = true
   end

   i += 1
end
```

1. Add dash before the number if odd, not the first one and previous char wasn't a dash.
2. Add the number.
3. Add dash after the number if odd and not the last one.

EDIT: Changed conditions on #1 to remove duplicate dashes.

Comment: This solution seems to work for most test cases with the exception of one: were all the digits in the input are odd (i.e. 333 or 13579 yields, 3--3--3 and 1--3--5--7--9, respectively). In this instance, it insets an extra "-" in between consecutive odd integers.   How could we eschew that?

Comment: Good point, you'll just need to remember if the last char added was a dash and not add the next one if that is the case.  I'll update my answer...

Answer (score 1):

If I may suggest a different approach to the problem. You can replace all the odd numbers with a pattern `-<current_odd_number>-` and then trim the leading & trailing `-`s.

```
def dash_odds(num)
  # num.to_s.gsub(/([13579])/, "-\\1-")[1..-2]
  num.to_s.gsub(/([13579])/, "-\\1-").gsub(/^\-|\-$/, '')
end
```

Edit: Thanks to Daniel Stevens, handled leading and trailing even numbers

Comment: Won't that trim leading and trailing even numbers?